# Difference between pyplot.imshow and image.show?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, prediction

I get the prediction results from the model I trained. But while I can easily show the predicted image with matplotlib, I cannot display it with PIL Image.
The image's shape is 256,256,3 in size and float32 type.
Image shown with matplotlib: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeoJ7.png) and Image shown with PIL Image: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbci2.png)

I use below code for matplotlib:

```
# gen_image is a list of predicted images
gen_image = (gen_image + 1) / 2.0
gen_image_convert = gen_image[0]
pyplot.imshow(gen_image_convert)
pyplot.axis('off')
pyplot.show()
```

and for PIL Image I used below code:

```
gen_image_convert = gen_image[0]
image = Image.fromarray((gen_image_convert * 255).astype(np.uint8)).convert('RGB')
image.show()
```

Comment: Probably `PIL` shows the values as they are, while `pyplot` assigns black to the lowest value seen and white to the largest.  You'll need the same transformation if you want to see the same result using `PIL`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It worked when normalize image to [0, 1].